# Magnetic field and AC current

Tags: electromagnetism

If I run an ac current under a plate of iron filings, what pattern should the filings form?

If I use the plug for an appliance, will the magnetic fields in the two wires cancel each other out (more or less)?

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: why the anonymous upvote?

Comment: if you're going to try this experiment, make sure the plate is something non-conductive, like plastic, cardboard, or maybe even a ceramic. Thicker plates reduce the effectiveness of these kinds of experiments.

Answer (score 1):

**AC current and Iron Fillings**

I'm assuming that this is just 1 wire with AC in it, and that it's parallel to the plane of the plate. Since this wire will produce a magnetic field (which varies in time), the individual fillings will act like little magnets, attempting to align with the field. Using the right-hand rule, I know that the field will be going into/out of the plate perpendicularly, so the fillings will simply "stand on end."

The AC part would make this interesting, though, because the strength and direction of the field varies with time. At the very least, you'll get fillings standing up (when the field is strong) and then going down (when the field is too weak to lift the magnets against gravity). If the iron fillings have some "memory" of which way they were magnetized, you may have fillings standing up, going down, and then flipping over.

**Two Wires' Fields Canceling The Other's Field**

It depends on the scales you're working with, and how precisely you measure these fields. If you are close to the wires, it matters more than if you are far from the wires.

If you're looking at a charged particle and which is really close to the wires, their fields only cancel each other out in special places. This means that, in other places, one field is stronger than the other. This would be a case where most people's sense of precision would indicate that these fields don't cancel each other out.

If you are looking at a charged particle far away, then the fields generally cancel each other out. This is because the distance from one wire compared to the distance to the other wire are "really close," or are better approximations of each other. Thus, the effects of each field are roughly the same in magnitude, and therefore cancel each other out.

If you have sensitive equipment, you could also detect the difference between the two at these far distances. For most applications, though, they cancel each other out very well.

This is a similar rationale for why solenoids "only" produce magnetic fields within the solenoid, and not outside them. In any case, if you're wondering if about a specific situation, you need to do the math and figure out if the fields are close enough practically cancel each other out, or if you need to worry about them.

Speaking from experience, if you're more than a few centimeters away and are performing experiments or other activities which are not super sensitive to magnetic fields, I would say they cancel each other out.